# Jersey restful web application returning 404 for all resource URI's

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, java-9

I'm new to restful web applications and I'm trying to create a restful web application using JAX-RS with help of jersey-api's.

When I try to access the application by some uri's each time I'm getting HTTP Status 404.

Please help me solve this problem.

Below are the code snippets

**MessageResource.java**

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("messages")
public class MessageResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMessages() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.manjunath.webservice.messenger</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Url used to access the resouce
**http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/messages**

I'm using jersey-quickstart-webapp with version 2.27

Attached the logs of tomcat server

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.get(LRUHybridCache.java:164)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:303)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3139)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2266)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities$3.run(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities$3.run(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:104)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.secureGetDeclaredMethods(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.getDeclaredMethodWrappers(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.getAllMethodWrappers(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:192)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.getAllMethodWrappers(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:193)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl$3.compute(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:84)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl$3.compute(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:111)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(LRUHybridCache.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:292)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1292)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1121)
    ... 108 more
MultiException stack 2 of 4
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl.getAllMethods(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl.getPostConstructMethod(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl.access$200(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl$1.compute(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:64)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl$1.compute(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:60)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:111)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(LRUHybridCache.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl.findPostConstruct(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:119)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.findPostConstruct(Utilities.java:1460)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DefaultClassAnalyzer.getPostConstructMethod(DefaultClassAnalyzer.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getPostConstructMethod(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:252)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getPostConstruct(Utilities.java:281)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post the startup logs of your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding following dependencies to the pom.xml the application started working.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, after adding the dependencies the code started working